# exception in RegEx

Tags: regex

I want to match a pattern but with some exceptions, how should I do it? Suppose the pattern is `[ivx]+` but I want to ignore the `i` and `vi` cases. I would like to match `ii`, `ix`, `v`, and `xxx`, but not `i` or `vi`.

Comment: *but with some exceptions* can you share them please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution myself.

`(?!\bvi\b|\bi\b)(\b[ivx]+\b)`